# Python complex object indexing - trouble accessing specific nested element

Tags: python, indexing

This is a training example that may or may not have application in the real world.  I have simplified it just to illustrate the problem.  Once built, I was having difficulty finding the right syntax to index a sub element.  Hoping someone can crack this ... just for the learning value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# some simple arrays:
simp1=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
simp2=np.array([[10,9,8,7,6]])
simp3=[11,12,13]

trueSimp1=np.array([10,9,8,7,6])

crazyList = [simp1, simp2, simp3, trueSimp1]
```

We can access the first element of the last object with:

```
crazyList[3][0]
```

We can view the whole first object with:

```
crazyList[0]
```

But how to get just a sub-element within the first object?  I tried many failed ideas of [0][1], [0,1], [[0]], [[0][1]] etc... and can't seem to find the right one to get at it.  Just for the learning, I would like add this answer to the notes I am building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For learnings' sake, you should know that this list is ideally a structure you would never ever have to deal with.

Your issue is that the first element in `crazyList` has an empty level of nesting (notice the extra square brackets). That is, the `ndarray` contains another `ndarray` containing the actual elements.

```
>>> crazyList[0]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> type(crazyList[0][0])
numpy.ndarray
```

Hence to access individual elements, you need to index the additional layer.

```
>>> crazyList[0][0][1]
2
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I was thinking of it as an array that was like a nested list but I somehow missed this meant there was an extra empty layer in it.  The code was borrowed from an instructor who I think may have failed to notice this detail as well, but we're only human.  :-)  In cleaning up my study NB, I may clean up the object so it is a nested object with something in each layer.  Still not realistic and there are probably better ways to organize data but the point is to show the complex indexing.  Thanks!

Comment: @TMWP No problem, glad I could help!